# Doctrine sqlfilter how to access to alias of oneToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a sqlFilter and I would like to filter on a OneToMany relationship

My Repository

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('employe');
$qb->leftJoin('employe.contrats', 'contrats', 'WITH');
```

And my filter

```
class DepartementFilter extends SQLFilter
{  
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
employeursArray=[1,2,3];

      if ($targetEntity->getReflectionClass()->name === 'App\Entity\Employe') {
 $sqlLocal = sprintf(
            'c1_.employeur_id IN (%s))',
            $employeursArray
        );     
    }
}
```

Filter works but I have harcoded alias "c1_"

I don't found how to get this alias name, because it's change on other pages

$targetTableAlias is the alias of Employe "e1_"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`addFilterConstraint` receive alias as second parameter. Replace by

```
$sqlLocal = sprintf(
            '%s.employeur_id IN (%s))',
            $targetTableAlias,
            $employeursArray
        );
```

You can check example in https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html#example-filter-class

Comment: Yes but my employeur_id field  is on contrat entity not employe entity
According to the documentation we can not access joined inheritance :
"In the case of joined or single table inheritance, you always get passed the ClassMetadata of the inheritance root"

Comment: What about ... `%s.contract_id in (propper subselect) `